# keyword this is not available in current context in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an interface called EventListener and there is a class called Endpoint which takes eventlistener as a parameter in method newInstance `newInstance(boolean debug, EventListener eventListener)` 
Now in my MainActivity class, when I implement EventListener and create an instance of endpoint its giving error called "keyword this is not available in current context" in C#.

```
    public class MainActivity : Activity, IEventListener {
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.newInstance(true, this);
    }
```

Surprisingly this error is not there in java. Can someone explain what's the difference.

Comment: C# and Java, although they have a similar syntax, are not the same. If you plan on doing a lot of C# development, especially since you're working with Xamarin, I suggest you read up on C# development. Xamarin takes the Android SDK and converts the Java idioms to C# ones. For example, getters and setters in Java are treated as properties in C#. So although it's fairly easy to "translate" Android code from Java to C#, there is still a slight learning curve to deal with. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `this` when initializing fields.  You'll need to initialize that field in a constructor if you want to use `this`.

Comment: So then how to call Endpoint.newInstance, I tried Endpoint.newInstance(true, typeof(MainActivity)); but no luck

Comment: Initialize it in the constructor, not in the field declaration. Just like Servy said.

Comment: but then how come it works in java. Sorry i'm new to C#

Comment: @Servy my constructor of Endpoint is private, then how can I call it in MainActivity.

Comment: @lijo050 You don't need to.  You're not trying to initialize a field of `Endpoint` using `this`, so that's not the constructor you need to put this code in.  You need to put it in the constructor of the object that has the field you're trying to initialize.

Comment: @Servy So you are saying to put it in the constructor of MainActivity ? Please provide a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

As per Servy's answer, you can't use `this` in an initialiser ([MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx)), but you can from a constructor. This should be approximately what you need:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, IEventListener
{
    private Endpoint endpoint; // could possibly be readonly

    public MainActivity()
    {
        endpoint = Endpoint.newInstance(true, this);
    }
}
```